# Get "primary" category image from WooCommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to get the featured image of the **"Primary" selected category** of a product.

Getting the images from the categories is not the problem, but how do I get the "primary" one?

Currently this is what I am using and of course getting all the images.

**I only want to display one image.**

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
            echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';
}?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _"Primary" selected category_? is it parent category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the terms with **`'parent`' argument equal to `0`**.

As you have set for your products only one **"primary"** product category for each normally, so we just take the first one anyway *(but you can have many for a product)*:

```
<?php

global $post;
$term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids', 'parent' => '0') );
if( count($term_ids) > 0 ){
    echo '<img src="'. wp_get_attachment_url( get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_ids[0], 'thumbnail_id', true ) ) .'" alt="" />';
}

?>
```

This is tested and works.

Comment: it works but not quite like I want it. Now when you change order of the categories the image also changes on the productpage. So apparently it is looking for an order too. Doesn't it save a value within the productpage itself marking it as the Primary one?

Comment: @Solomax Remember my intro *"As you have set for your products only one "primary""*… meaning that you need to have only one category by product *(but you can have many subcategories set in it)*… So only in this case the image will stay the same. if you have many categories in a product, the image will depend on categories order. Your question was not really explicit, see the question of **Raunak Gupta** … So if this is not convenient you can make a new question adding this code, and better explaining what do you have, How the categories are set in your products, and what do you expect to have…

Comment: check the image -> https://ibb.co/bYc25G

I want to show the image of the category set to "Primary" in the productpage

Comment: @Solomax … This is a custom feature in your theme (or maid with a plugin) that is not in by default in Woocommerce. So I really don't know how you can get this… You should better ask a new question adding all necessary details related to that "Primary" feature.

Comment: you are right. it is a Yoast feature. Let me rephrase the question in a new thread. thanks for your help